# creating a separate module with functions to make another code run in pygame

Tags: function, pygame

ok so i dont really understand functions atm and my assignment is to create a separate python module that has all of the functions need to make a program run. the program being supplied by the professor and is already completed and can not be changed by me. im not asking anybody to sit here and do all of the functions them self, although that would be amazing, i just need maybe 1 or two completed and maybe an explanation on how they work. below is completed program given to me.

```
import pygame
import lab06_bubbles as bubbles
import random

# @@@ NOTE: In this lab, I *DON'T* want you to change anything in this file. I want you to create
#           lab06_bubbles.py so that this works as described in the lab document (and video) @@@

# Pygame setup
win_width = 1200
win_height = 800
pygame.display.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier New", 12)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

numBubbles = random.randint(50, 100)                        # Initial number of bubbles
numWebs = 2                                                 # Initial number of connections between each bubble
paused = False                                              # Are we paused?
minAreaWidth = 50                                           # The minimum width of the bubble area
maxAreaWidth = win_width                                    # The maximum width of the bubble area
minAreaHeight = 50                                          # The minimum height of the bubble area
maxAreaHeight = win_height - 50                             # The maximum height of the bubble area

# Generate the initial play area and bubble list
currentArea = bubbles.randomArea(minAreaWidth, minAreaHeight, maxAreaWidth, maxAreaHeight)
bubbleList = bubbles.spawnBubbles(numBubbles, currentArea, 5, 20, 100)


# Game Loop
while not done:
    # @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    # @ UPDATE    @
    # @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    deltaTime = clock.tick() / 1000.0
    if paused:
       deltaTime = 0.0
    bubbles.updateBubbles(bubbleList, currentArea, deltaTime)

    # @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    # @ INPUT     @
    # @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            numBubbles -= 5
            if numBubbles < 5:
                numBubbles = 5
            bubbleList = bubbles.spawnBubbles(numBubbles, currentArea, 5, 20, 100)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            numBubbles += 5
            if numBubbles > 100:
                numBubbles = 100
            bubbleList = bubbles.spawnBubbles(numBubbles, currentArea, 5, 20, 100)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            numWebs += 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            numWebs -= 1
            if numWebs < 0:
                numWebs = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            currentArea = bubbles.randomArea(minAreaWidth, minAreaHeight, maxAreaWidth, maxAreaHeight)
            bubbleList = bubbles.spawnBubbles(numBubbles, currentArea, 5, 20, 100)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
            paused = not paused

    # @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    # @ DRAW      @
    # @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), currentArea, 1)
    bubbles.drawBubbles(bubbleList, screen, numWebs)
    screen.blit(font.render("# Bubbles: " + str(len(bubbleList)) + "  area: " + str(currentArea) + \
                        "   num_webs: " + str(numWebs), False, (128,128,128)), (0, win_height - 48))
    screen.blit(font.render("[Left / Right] : decrease / increase number of bubbles    [space]: regenerate bounds [escape]: quit", \
                        False, (128,128,128)), (0, win_height - 32))
    screen.blit(font.render("[Up / Down] : decrease / increase number of connections    [p]: pause", False, \
                        (128,128,128)), (0, win_height - 16))
    pygame.display.flip()

# Pygame shutdown
pygame.font.quit()
pygame.display.quit()
```

this is the function outline module that was given to me and this is where i have no idea what to do.

```
def randomArea(minW, minH, maxW, maxH):
 """
 :param minW: the minimum width of this box
 :param minH: the minimum height of this box
 :param maxW: the maximum width of this box (normally the width of the "playfield")
 :param maxH: the maximum height of this box (normally the height of the "playfield")
 :return: a pygame-style rect (x, y, w, h) that fits within the "playfield"
 """
def spawnBubbles(num, area, minSize, maxSize, maxSpeed):
 """
 :param num: the number of bubbles to create
 :param area: a pygame-style rect (x, y, w, h) that all bubbles should spawn completely inside
 :param minSize: the minimum size of a bubble
 :param maxSize: the maximum size of a bubble (should fit within the minimum size passed to
randomArea)
 :param maxSpeed: the maximum horizontal and vertical speed a bubble should have (in px / s)
 :return: A list of lists where each sub-list is of the form [x, y, radius, horiz_speed,
vert_speed]
 """
def getClosest(interest, L, num):
 """
 :param interest: the bubble of interest
 :param L: the list of all bubbles
 :param num: the number of closest bubbles to find
 :return: a list of num bubbles (not counting the interest) that are closest to the interest
object
 """
def updateBubbles(L, area, dt):
 """
 Makes all bubbles move. If a bubble hits the left / right sides of the area, negate their
horiz_speed and
 move them just inside the area; if a bubble hits the top / bottom of the area, negate their
vert_speed and
 move them just inside the area.
 :param L: The list of all bubbles
 :param area: the pygame-style rect bounding the play area.
 :param dt: The number of seconds that has passed since the last update
 :return: None
 """
def drawBubbles(L, surf, num_webs):
 """
 Draws the bubbles and the connections between them. This function calls the getClosest
function internally
 :param L: The list of all bubbles
 :param surf: The surface to draw to
 :param num_webs: The number of connections to draw between bubbles
 :return: None
 """
```

i just need some help with this please. this is what the [final product](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsxt2LpfScs&feature=youtu.be) should look like.

Comment: `randomArea` - you need `pygame.Rect()` and `random.randint()`

Answer (score 0):

First thing I won't do your assignment for you but I can try and help by giving you the following clues:

every time you use the import statement in a python script to import a module (fancy name for another script), Python will go and look for that module in two places:

- the current working directory (usually the folder where the script you are working on is)
- if it can't find it in the current working directory it will go and look for it in the Python installed libraries.

So the first thing you want, is to make sure that `lab06_bubbles` is in the same directory as the script you will run.

then, since your professor imports `lab06_bubbles` as `bubbles` , everywhere in his program where `bubbles.function` is mentioned it will go and look for that function in the lab06_bubbles.py file in which you have to build all the functions that the program will need.

Then the professor gives you all the information you need to build the function:

- what the arguments are
- what the function should return

You, have to do the magic in the middle.

say one of the functions was called `getDist` with the following description:

```
def getDist(pointa, pointb):
 """
 Takes two points, and return the distance between those points.
 :param pointa: a tuple with the x, y coordinates of point a
 :param pointb: a tuple with the x, y coordinates of point b
 :return: a float representing the distance between the two points
 """
```

you would need to code the function as follow:

```
def getDist(pointa, pointb):
    xa,ya = pointa
    xb,yb = pointb
    dist_ab = ((xa-xb)**2+(ya-yb)**2)**0.5
    return float(dist_ab)
```

hope that helps